# Why does the Ubuntu One website report my phone as "My Phone: Other/Unspecified"?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have a Samsung Galaxy 5, but the [Ubuntu One phone page](https://one.ubuntu.com/phones/) reports it as "Other/Unspecified"? How do I add my phone's information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That phone information page is merely to give you the right instructions for enabling contact sync on your phone, and the database (which we get from funambol) is by no means complete. Given that you're seeing that page for the first time with your phone already there, it means that you've successfully set up your phone without going via the phone setup webpage (yay for us! the installer works), so you don't need the instructions, so you should be fine.